# This batch control statement doesn't work the first time, but does the second time

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, label

Here's the code:

```
:login
    cls
    if exist "%~dp0\Users" (
        set /p enteredusername=Username: 
        if exist %~dp0\Users\%enteredusername%.bat ( call %~dp0\Users\%enteredusername%.bat ) else (
            echo.
            echo That user does not exist.
            echo.
            pause
            goto mainmenu
        )
    ) else (
        echo No accounts exist.
        echo.
        pause
        goto mainmenu
    )
    set /p enteredpass=Password: 
    if %enteredpass%==%password% ( goto begin ) else (
        echo.
        echo Incorrect password.
        echo.
        pause.
        goto mainmenu
    )
```

So the program accesses a batch file in the User folder. It's called whatever the username is.bat. For example, if the username that they registered is "Bob", the file would be Bob.bat. If that file exists, call it, setting the username and password variable. The issue is this: When I use this label the first time and am prompted to enter the username, I type in "Bob". It says that that doesn't exist (When in fact it does). Here's the curious part, though. The next time I run it and type in "Bob", it prompts me for my password and everything is grand. Why is it doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using %enteredusername% within the same IF construct as it is defined. The entire IF construct is LOADed (parsed) as one line.  So if you were to add a statement like

```
echo.enteredusername=%enteredusername%
```

immediately after the 'set /p...' line on which you set it you would see that the variable is empty.  You could enable delayedexpansion, but that presents a problem if your username or password has an "!" in it.  Safer solution would be to restructure something like this.  Obviously not all of your code is shown here.

```
login
cls
if not exist "%~dp0\Users" (
    echo No accounts exist.
    echo.
    pause
    goto mainmenu
)
set /p enteredusername=Username: 
if exist "%~dp0\Users\%enteredusername%.bat" ( call "%~dp0\Users\%enteredusername%.bat" ) else (
    echo.
    echo That user does not exist.
    echo.
    pause
    goto mainmenu
)
set /p enteredpass=Password: 
if "%enteredpass%"=="%password%" ( goto begin ) else (
    echo.
    echo Incorrect password.
    echo.
    pause.
    goto mainmenu
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect explanation. I've been trying to understand the purpose of enabledelayedexpansion does without luck, and now understand what everybody's been saying because of you.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Thanks for the kind words.